# Can mongod be executed without switching to directories where it is downloaded

Tags: mongodb

I am using mac.And to execute `mongodb` I am going to `downloads/mongodb/bin` folder and then execute `mongodb` file, Can I directly execute with out going to `downloads/mongodb/bin` ?

Comment: Where by "going" you mean "`cd` into that directory"? That is indeed not necessary. `~/downloads/mongodb/bin/mongod` should work just as well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev .I mean can I skip that cd downloads/MongoDB/bin . and just start executing on command line directly by any possible ways.

Comment: you maybe should write write a shell script and execute it from anywhere...

Comment: @ManjunathJoshi: yes, did you read my comment? It does not contain a `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole process is actually pretty well covered in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#id7):

What they suggest is to export the installation directory into your path environment variable like so:

```
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```